# DLink DWA 131 wireless adapter not working on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers

I recently purchased  DWA 131 adapter. Its not working on ubuntu. I upgraded to 15.10 hoping that it would work ... but no link ..

Please help.

lsusb output is :

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp.
```

dmesg output is :

```
[  691.728363] usb 1-3: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[  691.856817] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=2001, idProduct=3319
[  691.856822] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  691.856825] usb 1-3: Product: Wireless N Nano USB Adapter
[  691.856827] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  691.856829] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 00e04c000001
```

Comment: Please see: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/264654 Especially post #3.

Comment: @chili555 I can't believe that such a popular hardware is not supported on Ubuntu !! 
There has to be some way ... like compiling / manually installing driver .. otherwise what's the point of being Ubuntu !!

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/792779/167850

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this - https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
cd rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Comment: This worked ... I had to make a small change in the Make file because I got an error ...
I added following line in make file : EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wno-date-time

Let me test it for few days ... if it works without issues, I will accept this as answer

Comment: This driver does not work in Raspberry Pi2. Kerner version 4.1.13 v7+

Says recipe for target module failed in Makefile line 1323

Any idea how to get it working on Raspbian ?

Comment: Incredibly, this worked here. I just installed a test lubuntu 14.04 box under Virtualbox/Vagrant and this started up withou a hitch - within the VM.

Answer (score 11):

I packed this driver to a PPA with DKMS. It can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

I do not support this driver for 4.8+ kernels. For those who are using Ubuntu with 4.8+ kernels I suggest installing it from github using DKMS by

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Comment: it works too for:  TP-LINK TL-WN823N(EU) "VER 2.0

Comment: How can i use it for ver1.0? I tried to install it, the installation completed successfully, but the usb is not recognized (lsusb give me an empty line and the the green light is off)? btw - ubuntu 14.04 4.4.0-53-generic, TL-WN823N(EU)

Comment: I have no idea what v 1.0 is. Please ask a new question and post `lsusb` there.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood. I got the Ver 2.0 of the network stick. I got the same lsusb as here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/820886/problem-with-tp-link-tl-wn823n?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: With kernel 4.4 install the version for xenial. https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb

Comment: I done that, but my network stick still not recognized. I tried to install this before: https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver maybe I have a conflict or something? I'm a linux newbie

Comment: Ask a new question and explain what you do and what is the problem.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/859196/tp-wn823neu-ver-2-0-not-recognized-by-ubuntu-14-04-4-4-0-53-generic