# Problem with TP-Link TL-WN823N

Tags: wireless, 16.04, usb

Recently I installed Ubuntu 16.04 but cant get the usb wifi adapter to work properly , can anyone help me?

When wifi adpater is plugged , the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 2357:0109
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e0f:000b VMware, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

When wifi adapter is unplugged , the `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0e0f:000b VMware, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Are you in a virtual machine? You cannot use the host's usb devices unless you explicitly select it from your VM software.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DLink DWA 131 wireless adapter not working on ubuntu 15.10](http://askubuntu.com/questions/693500/dlink-dwa-131-wireless-adapter-not-working-on-ubuntu-15-10) as Pilot6 updated his rtl8192eu-dkms to include support for that 2357:0109 as there is no support from the Linux kernel for the device.  Mange updated his [github](https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver/commit/56ccb6b05cff08de1beddbbd03efdb36eff1416d) to support the device

Comment: @CelticWarrior, I am not the OP, but I can assure this is not necessarily a VM problem, since I'm experiencing the same issue on my single-boot Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @DavidFoerster, thanks for the link, but I believe this might not be VM-related. I am experiencing the very same issue on my single-boot Ubuntu desktop.

Comment: @Waldir Leoncio - Doesn't yours appear listed? The main problem here is out to "move" the device from the host to the guest OS in VMWare, as shown by the results above. If your doesn't work follow Jeremy31's comment.

Comment: @CelticWarrior, it doesn't appear listed, not even on http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids. However, I still managed to make it work by following your tip. I'll explain it in my answer below. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TP-LINK TL-WN823N Unable to connect to network](http://askubuntu.com/questions/813443/tp-link-tl-wn823n-unable-to-connect-to-network)

Comment: @DavidFoerster How is it related to a virtual machine?

Answer (score 7):

I was going through the same problem. Here is how to solve it, even though it doesn't solve the nameless problem:

**If you have wired internet available to your problem PC**

1. Follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/813034/48105), which adds Pilot6's `rtlwifi` PPA to your sistem and installs the required `rtl8192eu-dkms` package.

**If you have no internet access in your computer**

1. Find another computer with internet access to download the `rtl8192eu-dkms` package manually.
2. Access https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi
3. Click on "[View package details](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+packages)"
4. Filter your Ubuntu codename (16.04 LTS is Xenial).
5. Click on the triangle to open more options of "rtl8192eu-dkms - 4.4"
6. Download `rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb`.
7. Transfer this file to your target PC
8. Install the file on your target PC, either through the Software Center or the Terminal (by issuing `dpkg -i <filename>` in the appropriate folder).
9. Re-plug your dongle.

Here's a screenshot to better show the location of the download link:

Source of image: https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=xenial

[image: deb highlighted in blue]

Comment: @DavidFoerster You are wrong. The system does see the device. It is 2357:0109

Comment: it does see the device , it just doesn't recognise it , installing the drive should add the required udev config to have lsusb identify it

Comment: This is a correct answer. You can use my PPA. See the last comment under your question.

Comment: @Waldir Leoncio I do not have internet on my computer. I followed your answer up to #8 but it resulted in package dkms not installed . Any help?

Comment: @user278121, what is the terminal command you issued and what was the output?

Comment: I copied the file rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb in the Downloads folder of the target PC. cd into Downloads folder and ran this command: sudo dpkg -i rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb

Comment: Looks right. What was the output? Alternatively, try installing it by double-clicking on it. This should open the installer.

Comment: This was the output.
`(Reading database ... 173068 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb ...
Unpacking rtl8192eu-dkms (4.4) over (4.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rtl8192eu-dkms:
 rtl8192eu-dkms depends on dkms (>= 1.95); however:
  Package dkms is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package rtl8192eu-dkms (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rtl8192eu-dkms`

Comment: When I tried double-clicking, the Software Center window appeared but clicking on the Install button from there didn't change anything on the screen.

Comment: @user278121, well from "dependency problems" it seems like you're missing a package required by dkms to be installed. I'd recommend checking into that. Are you on 64 bits?

Comment: I installed the dkms package from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/dkms and then following your answer worked. The internet is now working fine. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @user278121. That is awesome, please remember to upvote!

Comment: @Pilot6 do you know of a working version for TL-WN823N US v3 by chance? These packages install but can't associate with a network.

Answer (score 6):

The driver for this dongle can be installed by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8192eu-dkms
```

Comment: Tested on 16.04 x64, kernel 4.4.0-36. It works great for me. My dongle: TP-LINK TL-WN823N(EU) "VER 2.0".