# TP-WN823N(EU) VER 2.0 not recognized by ubuntu 14.04 4.4.0-53-generic

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, usb

Have problems while trying to install the network stick.

Installed:

https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi/+files/rtl8192eu-dkms_4.4_all.deb

https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes

https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new

https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver

But USB not recognized:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:58f5 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


$ uname -a
Linux shai-PORTEGE-R835 4.4.0-53-generic #74~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 2 03:43:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


$ lsmod | grep 8192
8192eu               1732608  0 
rtl8192cu             630784  0 
snd                    81920  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device

$ cat /lib/modules/4.4.0-53-generic/modules.dep | grep 8192
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192ce/rtl8192ce.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192se/rtl8192se.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192de/rtl8192de.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl8192ee/rtl8192ee.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/btcoexist/btcoexist.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtl_pci.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/realtek/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192u/r8192u_usb.ko:
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib.ko: kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib_crypt_ccmp.ko: kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib_crypt_tkip.ko: kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib_crypt_wep.ko: kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtl8192e/r8192e_pci.ko: kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtllib.ko kernel/net/wireless/lib80211.ko
updates/dkms/8192cu.ko:
updates/dkms/8192eu.ko:
updates/dkms/rtl8192cu.ko:
```

Please give some advise, I'm lost here. Linux newbie BTW.

**--UPADTE --**

```
dkms status
8192cu, 1.10, 3.13.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
8192cu, 1.10, 4.4.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
8192cu, 1.10, 4.4.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192cu, 0.2~trusty, 3.13.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192cu, 0.2~trusty, 4.4.0-51-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192cu, 0.2~trusty, 4.4.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu, 4.4, 4.4.0-53-generic, x86_64: installed
```

How can I uninstall drivers?

*-- UPDATE 2 --*

```
usb-devices | awk '/0109/' RS=
T:  Bus=03 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=2357 ProdID=0109 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=Realtek 
S:  Product=802.11n NIC 
S:  SerialNumber=00e04c000001
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=500mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 5 Cls=ff(vend.) Sub=ff Prot=ff Driver=rtl8192eu
```

Comment: You installed too many drivers. You need to remove `8192eu` and install a driver from my PPA. I added this device there.

Comment: Please run `dkms status` and post the output.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: The correct driver is installed. You do not need `8192cu` and `rtl8192cu`, but that should not be an issue.

Comment: What does `usb-devices | awk '/0109/' RS=` show. Post it to your question please.

Comment: The driver is installed and used. I do not see a problem.

Comment: should it appear as Wi-Fi Network (RealTek 802.11n NIC) ? the green light on the stick is off and lsusb is the same as above.

Comment: @Pilot6 you didn't specify the address of your ppa

Comment: It looks that you installed the driver from my PPA. The `lsusb` is correct.

Comment: I removed the other dkms drivers. I did installed your PPA. I guess it works.  Except the lsusb looks weird

Comment: `lsusb` is not related. The description is not in the list for the device. It does not affect anything.

Comment: It is working! Thank you so much @Pilot6!