# cant get wireless adapter to work (TL-WN823n)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

Downloaded [DLink DWA 131 wireless adapter not working on ubuntu 15.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693500/dlink-dwa-131-wireless-adapter-not-working-on-ubuntu-15-10/813034#813034) - Pilot's driver, but doesn't seem to work.

Here is my dkms:

```
dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.8.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-340, 340.101, 4.8.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu, 4.4: added
```

Using Ubuntu 16.04.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2357:0109  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:3820 Alcor Micro Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0c45:8603 Microdia 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1532:0007 Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

$ dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.8.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-340, 340.101, 4.8.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu, 1.0, 4.8.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)
```

Edit: started using network manager instead of Wicd, now it works! thank you to pilot for all your help!

Comment: I am using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please post output of `lsusb`.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT POST IT TO COMMENTS. Post ALL additional information TO YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: Please post output of `dkms status` too.

Comment: Does it show the same now?

Comment: I asked you to post outputs to the question. Don't you see it is unreadable here? I am leaving.

Comment: I'm sorry, been sat heres for days trying get my ubuntu up and running, it's made me a little dumb im afraid haha thanks for ur help and sticking this far with me though!

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: i don't think i did the first part correctly, could you have a look at my outputs and tell me? the 3rd edit

Comment: Run the last three commands I added.

Comment: i get an error message on first line. edit4

Comment: I fixed a typo. Try now.

Comment: it seemed to work, i rebooted but no difference. dkms status is still identical to edit 2.  I will check if lsusb has changed edit: yes it is the same too : (

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you installed the `rtl8192-dkms` package from my (hanipouspilot) PPA.
It did not build for the 4.8 kernel, because I did not patch it for the 4.8 kernel yet.
I suggest running

```
sudo apt purge rtl8192eu-dkms
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
```

and installing the driver from github as mentioned in another answer.

Run

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8192eu/1.0 --all
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
```

Comment: in what order? if I remove it first how will i be able to download things from the internet?

Comment: How did you install it before?

Comment: I followed this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/693500/dlink-dwa-131-wireless-adapter-not-working-on-ubuntu-15-10/813034#813034

Comment: That answer has the command to install and download the driver from the Internet. And I see that the driver has been downloaded. That means that you had some connection.

Comment: excuse my ignorance. got to  git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git and i get
fatal: destination path 'rtl8192eu-linux-driver' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: OK. That means that you already downloaded the git. Skip this command.

Comment: I have followed the rest and will now reboot to test my tp link adapter. I will get back to you. Thank you for fast and useful replies! Blown away by the amazing support here, even if it can fall on dumb ears haha

Comment: It is still not working. I am also now recieving an error messge saying "System program problem detected". I am using wicd network manager.

Comment: This means that the module was not installed. Post all you did to your question with all terminal output. And also disable Secure Boot in your BIOS. That can be an initial problem.

Comment: sudo apt-get install git dkms
[sudo] password for dylan: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
git is already the newest version (1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1).
dkms is already the newest version (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  snap-confine
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.

Comment: git clone https://github.com/Mange/rtl8192eu-linux-driver.git
fatal: destination path 'rtl8192eu-linux-driver' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: sudo dkms add ./rtl8192eu-linux-driver
Error! DKMS tree already contains: rtl8192eu-1.0
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.

Comment: and lastly sudo dkms install rtl8192eu/1.0
Module rtl8192eu/1.0 already installed on kernel 4.8.0-42-generic/x86_64

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: how can i do that? I tried looking for it in the BIOS settings, could not find it there. Is it possible i do not have that option and how can i make sure?

Comment: If it is not UEFI, then you don't have it. Does `dkms status` show installed?

Comment: yes   dkms status
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.8.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-340, 340.101, 4.8.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8192eu, 1.0, 4.8.0-42-generic, x86_64: installed (WARNING! Diff between built and installed module!)

Comment: does not work for me